# SQL to find callers first and last phone call to the same person on a given day

Tags: sql, presto

Here's the table I am working with. Table name is phone_log

```
caller_id  recipient_id        call_start_time
1          2                  2012-04-19 09:00:00
2          3                  2012-04-19 17:00:00
1          2                  2012-04-19 23:00:00
...       ...                             ...
```

I need to find out who made their first and last call to the same person on a given day. I have no idea where to really begin. Appreciate any advice on this one.

My desired output would look like this:

```
caller_id    recipient_id        call_start_time
   1             2                 2012-04-19
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: I am using Presto.

Comment: Terrible title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method uses `first_value()`:

```
select distinct caller_id, first_recipient_id
from (select pl.*,
             first_value(recipient_id) over (partition by caller_id, date(call_start_time) order by call_start_time) as first_recipient_id,
             first_value(recipient_id) over (partition by caller_id, date(call_start_time) order by call_start_time desc) as last_recipient_id
      from phone_log pl
     ) pl
where first_recipient_id = last_recipient_id;
```

This uses a function such as `date()` which extracts the date from a date/time.  Date/time functions vary by database.

Comment: What would I need to do if I had to change it to require a minimum of two phone calls? I.E. How can I exclude a single person making a phone call, and it being counted?

Comment: Also, what if I needed the actual day in the output?

These are just extras I'd like to learn, your original query pulled the data correctly.

Comment: @bcoin_jake . . . You would just include `date(call_start_time)` in the outer query.